# ArcGIS Data Reviewer - extract results using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, data-reviewer

I'm evaluating the ArcGIS Data Reviewer extension to see if it suits our needs.  I've created a Python script that will run some data reviewer checks and I can confirm that is successfully writes results of invalid values to the Reviewer Table.

From there, I can use the Data Reviewer 'Options' button in ArcGIS to manually export the table to a spreadsheet or to run a report.

I would like to be able to export this data from the reviewer table using Python to fully automate the process.  However, I cannot find any way of doing so.

Is there any way to extract the Reviewer Table data using Python?

(Note that I can see that there are a set of tables in the reviewer GDB that I could theoretically query, but they are a set of related tables that would take a lot of work to get the data out in the same format as the reviewer table - which I guess is really just a view over this set of tables.  Can I do it without trying to recreate the Reviewer Table from these other low-level tables?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to extract DR results via Python by accessing the 'REVTABLEMAIN' table. If you use the MakeTableView tool, you can point your output to a specific session or drill down deeper than that. I then just run the TableToExcel tool to export my results with a name and date stamp. I have included a snippet of my main code and a snippet of the config file as well.

````
import utils.config as config
import arcpy
import pandas as pd
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
#run in task scheduler

print('Selecting Session 22')
arcpy.management.MakeTableView(config.DR_Table, "REVTABLEMAIN_View", "SESSIONID = 22", "IN_MEMORY")

print('Generating DR Spreadsheet')
arcpy.conversion.TableToExcel(config.DR_TABLE_VIEW, config.DR_EXCEL, "ALIAS", "DESCRIPTION")```


```import datetime
import os
import datetime
from datetime import date
SEP = os.path.sep

ROOT_DR_FOLDER = 

REVIEWER_DB = ROOT_DR_FOLDER + SEP + 'DataReviewer.gdb'

PRODUCTION_DB = DB Location

DR_Table = REVIEWER_DB + SEP + 'REVTABLEMAIN'

DR_TABLE_VIEW = "REVTABLEMAIN_View"

DR_SESSION_SQL = "SESSIONID = 22"

OUTPUT_FOLDER = ROOT_DR_FOLDER + SEP + 'OutputReports'

TODAY = date.today()

DT_FORMAT = TODAY.strftime("%m_%d_%Y")

DR_EXCEL = OUTPUT_FOLDER + SEP + "DR_Errors_" + DT_FORMAT + ".xlsx"
````

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've long-since given up on data reviewer (I can't even remember what we were attempting to achieve with it, back then), and have moved on to a different job now.  But your strategy sounds reasonable to me, so I'll mark your answer as correct anyhow.